# Listen to click events in generated HTML

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Basically I implemented a pipe, that generates HTML given some markdown like input. For links in the generated output I want to intercept the navigation event and perform some custom action on clicking the link.

To perform this custom action I implemented a directive that matches the generated links. While this directive works as desired for links that are part of a template, angular doesn't bind to the links in the pipe's output.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: "customlink"
})
export class CustomLinkPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
    let markdown: string = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value);
    markdown = markdown ? this._generateCustomLink(markdown) : markdown;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(markdown);
  }

  _generateCustomLink(href: string): string {
    return `<a appCustomLink href=${href}>Event Link from Pipe</a>`;
  }
}
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "a[appCustomLink]"
})
export class CustomLinkDirective {
  constructor() {}

  @Input("href") href: string;

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick(event: any): void {
    console.log(`href=${this.href}`);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

The below stackblitz is a MVCE to illustrate the problem

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hvusak

How can I make angular bind to the click events of the links in the pipe's output?

Comment: I think that your best bet is use renderer2 listen, https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen. The "target" is an html element that you can get using documents.getElementsByClass or another "javascript" method. Another option can be convert a string in a series of components like I tryed to do in this SO:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276306/dynamically-add-elements-to-the-editable-div-with-angular-and-anywhere/64277601#64277601

Comment: Yes, it very much looks like this. I ended up using `Renderer2` in an `@ViewChild` method, to register the listener.